# Problemas con la directiva ng-app de angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

buenos dias, tengo un problema en mi proyecto, al agregar la directiva `ng-app="miApp"`
Me arroja un error por la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De lo contrario al no colocar la directiva `ng-app="miApp"` no arroja ningun error, incluso colocando solo la directiva `ng-app` sin nombre de la aplicacion funciona perfectamente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="miApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AllMarket</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-include src=" 'plantillas/encabezado.html' "></div>
    <div ng-include src=" 'plantillas/menu.html' "></div>
    <h1>Visita el NG-ZOO</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li> <a href="#/animales/ave1">Ave 1</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#/animales/ave2">Ave 2</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#/animales/ave3">Ave 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

¿A que se debe el error que me arroja por consola?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es nesario que crees el módulo miApp, ejemplo:

```html
<html ng-app="App">
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('App',[]);
  </script>
   </head>
   <body><h1>App</h1></body>
</html>
```